# how to generate .ipa file from html5 project

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I developed an mobile app using JQuery Mobile Framework, in HTML5, CSS3 and JQuery/JavaScript. The files all have the extension .html or .css or .js...
Using the PhoneGap, I was able to convert the zipped folder to Android App (.apk), Windows Phone App, BlackBerry App and others, but I couldn't convert to iOS App (.ipa)...
It's a really simple app, so I just don't want to spend money on that. I don't have an Apple Developer License, I wanted to know if there is a way to try my app on my iPhone without paying, if is possible to create an Apple Developer License for free, or if there is a converter .apk to .ipa, or .zip to .ipa or ANYTHING like that.

Comment: You can try your app in Safari...

Comment: I am curios about this too!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the iPhone/iPad Simulator. To do so, you need a Mac computer, and you can download Xcode from the Mac AppStore for free. You can use Xcode to test your app on the simulator without having an Apple Developer Account. You just won't be able to build it on a real device.

But the thing is, if you want to publish your app on the AppStore, you will need to have an Apple Developper Account sooner or later. I strongly advise you to test on real devices before publishing anything. The simulator is great, but it's not like a real device. A lot of problem can come up on devices (mainly, memory and performances issues) and won't append in the simulator.

Comment: Hey, I can test the app on my device by hosting the code on the web and saving the site in the homepage of my iphone, i just want to know how to convert to .ipa